# Can Rinnegan users fly or levitate?

Tags: naruto

In the anime when Pain attacked Konoha, he levitated above the village before unleashing Almighty Push.

So my question is can Rinnegan users levitate?
If so, how? Constantly using small Almighty Pushes below his feet?

Comment: I don't think it's a combination of small almighty pushes since there's a recovery time after each almighty push. (Probably another power activated with the rinnegan)

Comment: @SahanDeSilva hmm I see. What if it's one almighty push, but he didn't push it all at once, but slowly? (at this point I don't know any other probability on how he could levitate. I mean even Rinnegan Sasuke never levitated)

Comment: I'm not quite sure since it's not mentioned anywhere. You could refer https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Rinnegan URL to read more on Rinnegan. :)

Answer (score 1):

## They can't.

In the manga, Pain's [Deva Path](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Deva_Path) jumps over the village and uses [Shinra Tensei](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Shinra_Tensei) to destroy it. Notice the fluttering cape.

[image]
[image]

Even when invading the village, Pain's [Animal Path](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Animal_Path) is thrown over Konoha's protective sphere.

[image]

At no point does Pain, his paths, Madara or Sasuke fly or levitate through the Rinnegan.

Answer (score 0):

It is not mentioned anywhere, plus in the final fight with Kaguya, Sasuske had Rinnegan and still couldn't levitate and eventually Naruto has to help him to stay above in the air in Lava Dimension.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is probably because of the special ability of the Pain Deva Path. Deva Path has the ability to manipulate the force, in here https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Deva_Path it is said that the ability can not be performed in rapid succession, but it has cooling down time about 5 seconds. So by manipulating force, Pain Deva Path can seem like levitating in the air.